# How to clean the obj and lib files generated by nmake

Tags: nmake

I am using nmake in VS 2012 console to compile GDAL, I want to know which command could help me to remove all files generated by nmake command last time.

```
c:\gdal>nmake clean

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.60610.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'clean'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got it, after having a look into makefile.vc, there is a clean target in it.
Just execute the following command:

```
nmake /f makefile.vc clean
```

Comment: NMAKE: fatal error U1052: file "makefile.vc" not found. stop.

Comment: Probably you have "Makefile" so change makefile.vc to Makefile in command and it should run.